# HTTP separation of Response Header and non HTTP Data

Tags: c++, http, boost, http-headers, boost-asio

I'm just writing a little client side HTTP application. It just sends a GET Request to an IP Camera and then receives a Screenshot in jpeg format.

Now for the implementation of HTTP I am using Boost Asio. So for the first try I oriented pretty much at the sync_client example [Boost Asio Sync HTTP Client Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp).

Now mainly I'm a bit worried by the separation of Headers and Data.

First I get the first line of the response:

```
boost::asio::streambuf response;
boost::asio::read_until(*m_Socket, response, "\r\n");

std::istream response_stream(&response);
std::string http_version;
response_stream >> http_version;

 if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
 {
     std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
     return;
 }

uint32_t status_code;
response_stream >> status_code;
std::string status_message;
std::getline(response_stream, status_message);  

 if (status_code != 200)    // 200 = status code OK
 {
     std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
     return;
 }
```

Now until here everything is clear to me.I'm reading until first new line and then check the stuff in my buffer.

Now I'm trying to read the second part of the header:

```
 boost::asio::read_until(*m_Socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

 std::string header;
 while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && (header != "\r"))
 {
      std::cout << header << "\n";
 }
 std::cout << "\n";
```

Now to this I have some questions:

1. The while loop is searching until there is a blank line ( the only line where a `\r` stands all by itself ). Now if I assume that a new line is defined by `\r` , why do I use `\r\n\r\n` at `boost::asio::read_until` ? I mean I would expect wether the one or the other, but both?
2. If I call the `boost::asio::read_until` method with `\r\r` as delimiter it throws an `End of File` exception.  This stands in contrary to what my while loop is searching since this is looking for a `\r\r` ( since it looks line after line, and every line closes with a `\r` )

So as you can see Im quite worried how to divide stuff inside my header. It's getting even worser because the `boost::asio::read_until` call does always read further than the delmiter ( this is actually OK, since it's mentioned in the documentation ), but still it kinda always has the same trail of data ( from the actualy jpeg ), with the same length following.

Maybe someone could enlighten me?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a [real, production-ready HTTP parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'\r' is the carriage return (CR) character and '\n' is the line-feed (LF) character.  HTTP message lines are terminated by "\r\n" (CRLF).

From "HTTP The Definitive Guide":

> It is worth pointing out that while the HTTP specification for
>   terminating lines is CRLF, robust application also should accept just
>   a line-feed character.  Some older or broken HTTP applications do not
>   always send both the carriage return and line feed.

What seems to be throwing you off is that some line I/O functions (in this case std::getline()) automatically strip the trailing '\n' so you are only seeing the preceding '\r'.  I think what you should be doing, is looking for a blank line (rather than a line with only '\r').  And a line that is only '\r' should be considered a blank line.

Comment: Ahhh yes now I get it...I didn't think about the fact that std::getline() may be cutting of some stuff. So if ( as you say ) the getline strips off the "\n" this makes way more sense!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `"\r\n\r\n"` delimiter is used to separate the headers from the actual server's response(which is the JPEG image you are fetching). That's why you're using it; headers are separated by `"\r\n"`.

You should read until `"\r\n\r\n"`. Everything that comes afterwards is the JPEG image. Note that you can guess the length of the file by checking the Content-Length header, or just read until the server closes the socket.